# How to evaluate indefinite integrals $\int\frac{e^{m \arctan x}}{(1+x)^{3/2}}\ dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int\frac{e^{m \arctan x}}{(1+x)^{3/2}}\ \operatorname{dx}$$

I tried solving with identities and searched around a bit but couldn't find a solution. How do we proceed?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: yes, I'm sure the denominator has the term (1+x)^3/2